# TensorFlowLite model for Object Detection throws ValueError on Loading

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

I am unexperienced with tensorflow.
I am using tensorflow 2.3.0 to create an object detection model with a custom dataset. The model I am using is the "ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_640x640_coco17_tpu-8".
Loading the trained checkpoint, I can use it to detect objects in an image which works great.

Now I saved the model using the SavedModel format using this command:
`python export_tflite_graph_tf2.py --trained_checkpoint_dir training --output_directory inference_graph_tflite --pipeline_config_path training/ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_640x640_coco17_tpu-8.config`

Then I converted the model to the TFLite format using this code:

```
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8,
                                       tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS]
tflite_model = converter.convert()

with open(path + 'final_detector.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)
```

This code is from the tensorflow docs. (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/lite/TFLiteConverter)

If I try to interprete this model I get this error:

```
  File "...\python\interpreter.py", line 197, in __init__
    _interpreter_wrapper.CreateWrapperFromFile(
ValueError: Did not get operators, tensors, or buffers in subgraph 0.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root of all my issues finaly. While I just followed the tensorflow docs, you need to downgrade tflite to the version 2.2.0 when using tensorflow 2.3.0. Rebuilding the tflite model works.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the graph is correctly converted, using tools such as [netron](https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron)?

Comment: It looks like it should, the input node and the 4 output nodes are there.